# Zend Form elements in div

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, zend-form, decorator

I am creating a form, using Zend Form. I have 8 input elements. And I want to placing first 6 elements in one div, and others in second. How I can do this?
I am tried to use addDisplayGroup(), but it was unsuccessful.

Or may be you know how to create a link in form?

Comment: `addDisplayGroup()` will put them in a fieldset by default. In what way was `addDisplayGroup()` unsuccessful? Does it need to be a div or can it be a fieldset?

Comment: Yes. It should be a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a [decorator](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450-Decorators-with-Zend_Form), such as Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag.

Comment: How? May be some examples fro my situation?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450, at "Example: Full Customization Using the ViewScript Decorator"